# nftw passing tflag with undefined value

Tags: c, linux, unix, nftw

While traversing a directory using nftw like so,

```
nftw((argc < 2) ? "." : argv[1], rm, 20, FTW_DEPTH|FTW_PHYS)
```

nftw is passing a value of 5 to the rm function's tflag parameter when it encounters a directory. The ftw.h header only specifies an enum with 4 values (0-3) for the tflag parameter, of which FTW_D or 1 is the appropriate value for a directory. The fpath value appears to be correct in all instances.

So my question is this. Why is it passing 5 and not 1 for the tflag, and what does 5 mean for the tflag?

EDIT:

The value was in fact FTW_DP (Directory, all subdirs have been visited) which was defined below in an environment dependent portion which I failed to notice.

Comment: [**This** version of the header file](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/histar/src/pkg/uclibc/include/ftw.h) indicates that 5 is `FTW_DP /* Directory, all subdirs have been visited. */`

Comment: @jedwards Stepping through the program, that does appear to be the case. Looking at the header again I now see that the enum does not end where I thought it did. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POSIX specification of [`nftw()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html)
says that the flag argument to your `rm` function shall be one of:

> - `FTW_D`
>     The object is a directory.
> - `FTW_DNR`
>     The object is a directory that cannot be read. The fn function shall not be called for any of its descendants.
> - `FTW_DP`
>     The object is a directory and subdirectories have been visited. (This condition shall only occur if the FTW_DEPTH flag is included in flags.)
> - `FTW_F`
>     The object is a non-directory file.
> - `FTW_NS`
>     The stat() function failed on the object because of lack of appropriate permission. The stat buffer passed to fn is undefined. Failure of stat() for any other reason is considered an error and nftw() shall return -1.
> - `FTW_SL`
>     The object is a symbolic link. (This condition shall only occur if the FTW_PHYS flag is included in flags.)
> - `FTW_SLN`
>     The object is a symbolic link that does not name an existing file. (This condition shall only occur if the FTW_PHYS flag is not included in flags.)

Since you don't identify your system and the standard doesn't define what number shall be associated with the flag argument to the called function, no-one can identify what the `5` means on your system.  However, there are enough options that `5` doesn't seem implausible as a value.

On Mac OS X (10.9.5), the value `5` would be `FTW_SL`. On another system, based on OSF, [jedwards](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736937/jedwards) notes in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061399/nftw-passing-tflag-with-undefined-value/26061557#comment40830356_26061399) that the value `5` is for `FTW_DP`, thus fully justifying my observation that the flag represented by `5` is system-dependent.